# How to deal with cases that cell is too long to display?

Tags: longtable

Some times I encounter a problem: some cells are too long to display and I have to break manually. 
So my question: Is there a method making it automatically? I have tried `supertabular` and `longtable`, but they do not seem to work. Did I use them incorrectly?

For example,

```
\begin{supertabular}{|c|c|}\hline
A poem &A man is bringing a cup of coffee to his face, 
tilting it to his mouth. It's historical, he thinks. 
He scratches his head: another historical event. 
He really ought to rest, he's making an awful lot of 
history this morning.
Oh my, now he's buttering toast, another piece of 
history is being made.
He wonders why it should have fallen on him to be 
so historical. Others probably just don't have it, 
he thinks, it is, after all, a talent.
He thinks one of his shoelaces needs tying. Oh well, 
another important historical event is about to take 
place. He just can't help it. Perhaps he's taking up 
too large an area of history? But he has to live, hasn't 
he? Toast needs buttering and he can't go around with 
one of his shoelaces needing to be tied, can he?
Certainly it's true, when the 20th century gets written 
in full it will be mainly about him. That's the way the 
cookie crumbles--ah, there's a phrase that'll be quoted 
for centuries to come.\\
\hline

\end{supertabular}
```

There is only 1 row with 2 columns. But the second cell is quite enormous to display.

Comment: \begin{supertabular}{|c|p{10cm}|} ... does the job.

Comment: @wasteofspace Could you make your comment an answer?

Comment: @wasteofspace Please, add an answer

Answer (score 2):

To have text break within a table, you can use a paragraph column, which is specified with `p{<width>}`, so for example

```
\begin{supertabular}{|c|p{10cm}|}
...
```